# How to pass variable and get data from API in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image]

This the first UI in there when user enter channel name and after click join then should it pass "loadData" method in there that channel name should pass to "API" and get **channelname** and **appId**  from that url.

**join button code**

```
  Future<void> onJoin() async {

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => loadData(myController.text)),
    );
  }
```

**loadData method**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import '../model/appIdModel.dart';


class ApiService {
  loadData(String myController) async {
    final String url ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1=$myController';

    Future<List<Data>> getData() async {
      Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 2000) {
        Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);
        List<dynamic> body = json['data'];

        List<Data> datas = body.map((dynamic item) => Data.fromJson(item).toList();
            return datas;
            } else {
            throw ('cannot fetch data');
            }
        }
  }


}
```

**Data model code**

```
class Data {
  String appId;
  String channelName;

  Data({
    required this.appId,
    required this.channelName,
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
        appId: json['appId'] == null ? null : json['appId'],
        channelName: json['channelName'] == null ? null : json['channelName']);
  }
}
```

then **appId** and **channelName** should fetch

FutureBuilder widget code show **channelId** and **channelName** (Home page code)

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  bool _validateError = false;

  ApiService client = ApiService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20)),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: myController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Channel Name',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                      hintText: 'test',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
                      errorText:
                          _validateError ? 'Channel name is mandatory' : null,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30)),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: onJoin,
                    height: 40,
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: const <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Join',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_forward,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: client.getData(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<List<Data>> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          List<Data>? data = snapshot.data;
                          return ListView.builder(
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        data![index].channelName.toString(),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        data[index].appId.toString(),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ));
                        }
                        return const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> onJoin() async {
    setState(() {
      myController.text.isEmpty
          ? _validateError = true
          : _validateError = false;
    });

    // await _handleCameraAndMic(Permission.camera);
    // await _handleCameraAndMic(Permission.microphone);

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => loadData(myController.text)),
    );
  }
```

this is the my code to fetch data.when I run the url with channel name then data show nicely.
[image]
I tired to fetch "channelName" and "appId" using this url.

Comment: in what class did you use your FutureBuilder? in the same page that you input and join button are placed?

Comment: yes  join button are placed page used

Comment: could you include the full code of that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong when you call `onJoin`, change it to this:

```
Future<void> onJoin() async {
  future = client.getData(myController.text);
}
```

then define new variable like this:

```
Future<List<Data>>? future;
```

then change ApiService to this:

```
class ApiService {

  final String url =
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
  Future<List<Data>> getData(String myController) async {
      Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url + myController));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) { // <--- change this
        Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);
        List<dynamic> body = json['data'];

        List<Data> datas = body.map((dynamic item) => Data.fromJson(item).toList();
            return datas;
            } else {
            throw ('cannot fetch data');
            }
        }
}
```

then change your `FutureBuilder` to this

```
future != null ? FutureBuilder(//<--- add this
                  future: future,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                      case ConnectionState.waiting:
                        return const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      default:
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                        } else {
                          future = null; //<--- add this
                          List<Data> data = snapshot.data ?? []; //<-- change this
                          return ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: data.length, //<-- add this
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        data[index].channelName.toString(),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        data[index].appId.toString(),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ));
                        }
                    }
                  },
                )
              : SizedBox(),//<--- add this
```

also as you can see in your postman result the `data` contain a `map`, not list of map, so if you expect a `list` you need to contact to your backend but if not you can parse it like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> body = json['data'];
List<Data> datas = [Data.fromJson(body)];
```

also for ui issue you can't use `listview` inside `SingleChildScrollView`, for that you need set `shrinkWrap` to `true`, also set its physics to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` too:

```
return ListView.builder(
   shrinkWrap: true,
   physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
   itemBuilder: ...
)
```

Comment: at the "ApiService" show this error "A value of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Data>'. (Documentation)  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<Data>'." I will add image

Comment: I updated my answer. check it out. @DasunDola

Comment: where I add "List<Data> datas = [Data.fromJson(item)]; " this

Comment: when add for "List<Data> datas = body.map((dynamic item) => Data.fromJson(item).toList();" then show this "Undefined name 'item'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name."

Comment: replace `List<Data> datas = body.map((dynamic item) => Data.fromJson(item).toList();` with `List<Data> datas = [Data.fromJson(item)];`

Comment: I will add image

Comment: sorry my bad, I updated my answer again.

Comment: No worries bro. Now runing with out any errors but didn't show appId and channelName only show " CircularProgressIndicator"

Comment: I updated my answer again, lets see is there any error or not. check it.

Comment: yeah now that's worked but  show 'cannot fetch data '

Comment: you need also change `if (response.statusCode == 2000) {` to `if (response.statusCode == 200) {`. we don't have 2000 status code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250653/discussion-between-dasun-dola-and-eamirho3ein).

Comment: bro now worked prefect but at the console show this error I will add image